# Remove interface in the replay in Street Fighter V

Tags: street-fighter-v

How can I remove the whole interface when I watch a replay in Street Fighter V (the box with the "replay" text included)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not officially supported. It could be intentionally like that.
Unless maybe by modding the game, there isn't any way to do this.